# Multiple Functions for Reading Data

Tags: scala

I'd like to be able to read data for some application in many different ways (e.g. reading from a file, fetching data from a mongo or a postgres db, applying operators on the incoming data "on the fly" etc.) Maybe I'm wrong but I thought a good way to do this would be something like that (the following is just an example):

```
trait Options

//Pass the path to a data file to the constructor
class FromFileOptionsWrapper(val file: String) extends Options

//Pass the name of a database to the constructor
class FromDBOptionsWrapper(val db: String) extends Options 

// A get-data function
def getFileData(opts: FromFileOptionsWrapper): Iterator[DataPoint] = {
  val readFromFile = opts.file
  //Logic to get data from readFromFile follows.
  //Returns an iterator of datapoints that will be consumed by the app.  
}

//Another get-data function
def getDBData(opts: FromDBOptionsWrapper): Iterator[DataPoint] = {
  val readFromDB = opts.db
  //Logic to get data from readFromDB follows. 
  //Returns an iterator of datapoints that will be consumed by the app.  
}

//An app-runner method
def run(opts: Options, dataFunc: (Options) => Iterator[DataPoint] ) {

  val data = dataFunc(opts)

  data foreach { dataPoint =>
    //do the work...
  }
}


/* Usage: */

val opts1 = new FromDBOptionsWrapper("my-db")
run(opts1, getDBData)

val opts2 = new FromFileOptionsWrapper("/home/me/data.txt")
run(opts2, getFileData)
```

The problem is that this approach doesn't work, the `run` method gives an error that looks like this:

```
Type missmatch, expected: (Options) => Iterator[DataPoint], actual: 
(FromDBOptionsWrapper) => Iterator[DataPoint]
```

I looked at the documentation and I show that function types are contra-variant to their "domain" types, so it's natural for the error to occur, since the `run` method is expecting something of the form `(A) => B` and I'm passing something like `(C) => B` with `C` a subclass of `A`.

I was wondering if there is a way to overcome this problem. Or, if you think that the approach is completely off-track and there is some standard way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It seems a little off track, why not make `FromFileOptionsWrapper` just extend `Iterator[DataPoint]`? then your function would just take `Iterator[DataPoint]`. Part of the problem is that the `Options` trait has no useful API. Another approach would be to make an abstract `iterator: Iterator[DataPoint]` method in the `Options` trait, that all subclasses must implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution is to parameterize the `run` method:

```
def run [T <: Options](opts: T, dataFunc: T => Iterator[DataPoint] ) {...}
```

But generally I follow this rule: Move the code that requires some type knowledge to the compilation unit that happens to have that knowledge.

In this case:

```
trait Options {
  def iterator: Iterator[DataPoint]
}

class FromFileOptionsWrapper(val file: String) extends Options {
  lazy val iterator: Iterator[DataPoint] = {
    val readFromFile = opts.file
    //Logic to get data from readFromFile follows.
    //Returns an iterator of datapoints that will be consumed by the app.  
  }
}

def run(opts: Options) {
  opts.iterator foreach { dataPoint =>
    //do the work...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, it did compile ... How would you possibly implement it?
Some functions need `FromFileOptionsWrapper`, some need `FromDBOptionsWrapper`, but you don't have either of those, you only have `Options`. How would you call the function that gets passed in?

There are different ways to do what you want, depending on what yoru `Options` thingy really is.

The easiest, probably is to "teach" the `Options` itself retrieve the data, rather than passing it to a separate function:

```
trait Options {
  def data: Iterator[DataPoint]
}

class FileOptions extends Options {
  def data = getFileData(this)
}

class DBOptions extends Options {
   def data = getDBData(this)
}

def run(options: Options) = options.data foreach { dataPoint => ... }
```

But at this point, it becomes obvious, you don't really need `Options` to begin with. Why not just `def run(it: Iterator[DataPoint]) = it.foreach ..`?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is because of passing 'getFileData' to run method.  not 'opts2' parameter.

opts2 is subclass of Options and can be used as Options parameter.

But 'FromFileOptionsWrapper' cant be cast to '(Options) => Iterator[DataPoint] '.

FromFileOptionsWrapper is subclass of Options. not parent!